# IosSlider не работает с сервера

Tags: jquery

Добрый день!

Проблема следующая:

Есть адаптивный сайт. В мобильной версии которого ($(window).width() < 520)) есть слайдер iosSlider.

Если открывать данную страницу локально, то все работает корректно, но когда заливаю на сервер и открываю страницу, то данный слайдер не работает.

В чем может быть причина (работает локально, но не работает на сервере)?

firebug пишет следующее:

```
TypeError: $(...).iosSlider is not a function
scrollbarContainer: '.sliderContainer .scrollbarContainer'
```

и

```
Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое, что приходит в голову - не правильно указан путь к файлу плагина или сам файл не загружен на сервер. Так или иначе, но ошибка свидетельствует о том, что плагин не подгружен на страницу.

Comment: @Deonis, да, действительно, Вы правы. Глаз уже замылился... Спасибо!

Пожалуйста, преобразуйте Ваш комментарий в ответ.